# Image should not use full-width in element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

At the moment I am trying to program the wireframe I have made, but experience some problems with specially the left side of the element:

[image]

The problem is that the 200x200px image is going full width in the left column. Therefore I cannot center the image.

I can see it can be changed with overwriting the following CSS, and set the `width to none;`.

```
.cms-area img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

But as I see it will break the reponsive on the images?

Can anybody help me in goal here?

See the [Testpage here][2].

The site is still using Bootstrap 3, and I do not have access to change the main CSS. Therefore I need to overwrite CSS if I need that.

Best regards

```css
<style>
    #front .row {
        padding-bottom: 0px;
    }
    .row [class*="col-"] {
        padding-right: 7.5px;
        padding-left: 7.5px;
    }
    .padding-white-bg {
        padding: 15px;
        background-color: #fff;
        margin-bottom:30px;
        border: 1px solid #ebecf0;
    }
    .padding-twocolumn-bg {
        margin-bottom:30px;
    }
    .padding-grey-bg {
        padding: 7.5px;
    }
    .padding-white-border {
        border: 1px solid #ebecf0;
    }
    .top-pad-d {
        padding-top: 15px;
    }
    .sbp-2-column {
        background-color:#fff;
        padding-top:15px;
        padding-bottom:15px;
        border:1px solid #ebecf0;
    }
    /********************************/
        /*       Product styling       */
        /********************************/
    
    /* Make spot image go full width */
    .cms-area .result-cols ul.items li.add-item {
        width: 100% !important;
    }
    .cms-area .result-cols ul.items li.add-item .item {
        padding: 0px;
    }
    /* Remove add to basket button */
    .cms-area .result-cols ul.items li.add-item a.button-add {
        display:none;
    }
    /* Set height on product description */
    .cms-area .result-cols ul.items li.add-item .desc {
        height: 0px;
        overflow: visible;
    }
    /* Remove fade on product headline */
    .cms-area .result-cols ul.items li.add-item .desc:after {
        background: none;
    }
    .cms-area .result-cols .more-wrap {
        padding-bottom: 0px;
    }
    /* Remove Sub-heading */
    .desc2{
        display:none;
    }
    /* Remove product text */
    .ext-description {
        display:none;
    }
    /* Remove padding multiple products on row */
    .cms-area .result-cols {
        padding:0px;
    }

    /********************************/
    /*          Custom Buttons      */
    /********************************/
    .btn.btn-lg {padding: 10px 40px;}
    .btn.btn-hero,
    .btn.btn-hero:hover,
    .btn.btn-hero:focus {
        color: #f5f5f5;
        background-color: #1abc9c;
        border-color: #1abc9c;
        outline: none;
        margin: 20px auto;
    }
    
    /********************************/
    /*          Media Queries       */
    /********************************/
    @media screen and (min-width: 980px){
        .hero { width: 980px; }    
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 640px){
        .hero h1 { font-size: 4em; }    
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 896px){
        .top-pad-m { 
            padding-top: 15px;
        }    
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1280px) {
        .fade-carousel .slides .slide-1, 
        .fade-carousel .slides .slide-2,
        .fade-carousel .slides .slide-3 {
            height: 60vh;
        }
    }
    /********************************/
    /*          Overall Styling      */
    /********************************/
    #sbp-hr {
        margin-top:10px !important;
        margin-bottom:10px !important;
    }
    .sbp-align {
        text-align: left;
        padding-left:10px;
    }
    .test {
        padding:20px 20px 20px 20px;
    }
    /* TEST on 2 column */
    .classWithPad { margin:8px; padding:10px; background-color: #fff; border:1px solid #ebecf0;}
    .cms-area img {
        max-width: 100%;
    }

</style>
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <!-- Section 7 -->
    <div class="section padding-twocolumn-bg">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="text-center col-md-6">
                <div class="classWithPad">
                    <p style="padding:75px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                    <a><img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" class="img-responsive test"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center col-md-6">
                <div class="classWithPad">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <h3 class="sbp-align">Headline</h3>
                            <hr>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <img src="https://placehold.it/250x150" style="padding:10px;">
                            <h4 class="sbp-align">Subline</h4>
                            <p class="sbp-align">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                            <hr id="sbp-hr">
                            <a href="#">Read more</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <img src="https://placehold.it/250x150" style="padding:10px;">
                            <h4 class="sbp-align">Subline</h4>
                            <p class="sbp-align">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                            <hr id="sbp-hr">
                            <a href="#">Read more</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why remove width:100% will break the responsive?

Comment: The 2 columns to the right is not going full width, when you minimize the window.

Comment: remove it only for the left image, no need to touch the right one

Comment: Ok - How am I gonna do that?

Comment: for example `.col-md-6 a img {
    width: auto;
}` --> you consider selector that will select only the first image, you can find a lot

Comment: Ok thanks. And I place the image and text with padding then?

Comment: you add margin:auto also to center it

Comment: Ok thanks you a lot, could you please take a look at the link now? So the last thing is how can I make sure that the 2 columns is gonna have the same height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make `width=200px` to the left column the uploaded image will always be at center and there are lots of `padding` you are using for centering the images, you can use various `classes` of bootstrap for that!

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">



<div class="container-fluid">
  <!-- Section 7 -->
  <div class="section padding-two column-bg">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
      <div class="text-center col-md-6 col-12">
        <div class="classWithPad">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          <a><img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" width="200px"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="text-center col-md-6">
        <div class="classWithPad">
          <div class="row p-3">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <h3 class="sbp-align">Headline</h3>
              <hr>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <img src="https://placehold.it/250x150" width="100%" class="pb-2">
              <h4 class="sbp-align pb-2">Subline</h4>
              <p class="sbp-align">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
              <hr id="sbp-hr">
              <a href="#">Read more</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <img src="https://placehold.it/250x150" width="100%" class="pb-2">
              <h4 class="sbp-align">Subline</h4>
              <p class="sbp-align">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
              <hr id="sbp-hr">
              <a href="#">Read more</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As I wrote I cannot use BS3